# jQuery insert HTML with script tags to DOM

Tags: jquery, insert

I have a bunch of unknown HTML with scripts tags that I wanted to be inserted into the DOM, i.e.

```
<blockquote>blah blah...</blockquote><script...></script>
```

But using

```
$('.element').html(theString);
```

will produce an error because of the closing `</script>` tag.

What could be a workaround for this?

Edit: Unfortunately, I can't modify the strings. It's dynamically generated and it can contain just any other tags.

Answer (score 0):

A hacky workaround is to split up the  tag like so:

```
var string = "<blockquote>blah blah...</blockquote><script></scr" + "ipt>"
$('.element').html(string);
```

This will prevent the HTML parser from thinking it's the end of the script.

Or, assuming that your dynamically generated string is "X", you can call:

```
X.replace(/<\/script>/ig, "<\\\/script>"); //this changes </script> to <\/script>
$('.element').html(X);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't modify the strings.

Comment: Let me know if the updated answer is what you're looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Just use native innerHTML

```
$('.element')[0].innerHTML = string;
```